# How to get all points contained within an SVG path string without checking every point on canvas?

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, html5-canvas

Is there an efficient way to find the `[x, y]` coordinates of every point in a inside a path without manually checking every point on the entire canvas using `context.isPointInPath()`?

Sample path from a geojson

```
<path d="
  M 588, 173,
  L 588, 176,  L 585, 216,  L 585, 216,  L 584, 223,
  L 580, 274,  L 565, 273,  L 565, 273,  L 549, 271,
  L 539, 270,  L 535, 269,  L 513, 267,  L 503, 266,
  L 486, 264,  L 477, 262,  L 468, 261,  L 464, 260,
  L 455, 259,  L 449, 258,  L 451, 249,  L 452, 244,
  L 453, 233,  L 456, 218,  L 456, 215,  L 460, 192,
  L 460, 191,  L 462, 180,  L 463, 174,  L 463, 171,
  L 464, 167,  L 464, 161,  L 465, 158,  L 470, 159,
  L 471, 159,  L 477, 160,  L 477, 160,  L 480, 161,
  L 482, 161,  L 487, 161,  L 499, 163,  L 500, 163,
  L 514, 165,  L 534, 168,  L 535, 168,  L 544, 169,
  L 555, 170,  L 557, 170,  L 565, 171,  L 581, 173,
  Z"  
fill="transparent" stroke-width="1" stroke="black"></path>
```

For example, this is what I'm doing now with a geojson file:

```
  const points = [];
  const pointWidth = 2;

  for (let x = 0; x < canvasWidth; x += pointWidth) {
    for (let y = 0; y < canvasHeight; y += pointWidth) {

      for (const feature of countyGeoJson.features) {
        const d = pathGenerator(feature);
        const countyShape = new Path2D(d);

        if (context.isPointInPath(countyShape, x, y)) {
          points.push({ coords: [x, y], data: feature.properties });
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Basically, I'm looping through every point in the canvas grid (there are over one million), and nesting another loop that looks through every feature to determine if the point is in the feature's projected path string. That is terribly inefficient and my browser cannot handle it.

Is there a way to use the path string itself to generate the points?

Comment: Can you post some sample SVG

Comment: The SVG is projected GeoJSON. I'm working with U.S. states, so I need to find every point within each state.

Comment: Here's an example. This is the state of Wyoming: https://pastebin.com/iTPNj5gt

Comment: I cleaned up that example and added it to your question... that path has only lines, as long as all are like it should be easy for you to read that and get all points from that

Comment: I'm looking for all the elements *inside* the path, not on the path outline

Comment: Do you need to get every point with integer coordinates that are contained inside that path?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And each point is a square of a specific pointWidth, ie. 2 pixels by 2 pixels.

Comment: Do you have list of points that defines the path available in an array, or in some other structure in javascript?

Comment: I could get the points from the coordinates - but if the path is is not a rectangle, I don't know how that would help me

Comment: the points (path outline) form a polygon, it does not matter the shape (rectagle or not) there are very efficient algorithms for that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon#Ray_casting_algorithm and yes @Luka's answer helps you reduce the amount of points you check... will try to get you a full solution later

Comment: I have missed some important details from the question, my previous answer will not work. I just posted another different answer.

Comment: @InspectorDanno was any of the answers satisfactory?

Comment: Both of you had good answers - although the ray-casing algorithm is much quicker than looping over each point in the canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full implementation from what we discussed on the comments

```js
var image = `
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="800" height="400" version="1.1">
        <path d="
            M 588, 173,
            L588,176,  L585,216,  L585,216,  L584,223,  L580,274,  L565,273,  L565,273,  L549,271,
            L539,270,  L535,269,  L513,267,  L503,266,  L486,264,  L477,262,  L468,261,  L464,260,
            L455,259,  L449,258,  L451,249,  L452,244,  L453,233,  L456,218,  L456,215,  L460,192,
            L460,191,  L462,180,  L463,174,  L463,171,  L464,167,  L464,161,  L465,158,  L470,159,
            L471,159,  L477,160,  L477,160,  L480,161,  L482,161,  L487,161,  L499,163,  L500,163,
            L514,165,  L534,168,  L535,168,  L544,169,  L555,170,  L557,170,  L565,171,  L581,173,
            Z" fill="transparent" stroke-width="1" stroke="black">
        </path>
    </svg>`;

function inside(p, vs) {
    var inside = false;
    for (var i = 0, j = vs.length - 1; i < vs.length; j = i++) {
        var xi = vs[i][0], yi = vs[i][1];
        var xj = vs[j][0], yj = vs[j][1];
        var intersect = ((yi > p[1]) != (yj > p[1])) && (p[0] < (xj - xi) * (p[1] - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi);
        if (intersect) inside = !inside;
    }
    return inside;
}

function draw() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    const matches = image.matchAll(/L(...),(...),/g)
    const poly = Array.from(matches, m => [Number(m[1]), Number(m[2])])

    let xs = poly.map(p => p[0]);
    let ys = poly.map(p => p[1]);
    let [xmin, xmax] = [Math.min(...xs), Math.max(...xs)];
    let [ymin, ymax] = [Math.min(...ys), Math.max(...ys)];

    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5
    const pointWidth = 4
    for (let x = xmin; x <= xmax; x += pointWidth) {
        for (let y = ymin; y <= ymax; y += pointWidth) {
            if (inside([x, y], poly)) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = Math.random()<0.5? "blue" : "red"
                ctx.arc(x, y, 1.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.fill();               
            }
        }
    }
}

var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


var img = new Image();
img.onload = draw
img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(image);
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=800 height=400></canvas>
```

- `function inside` is the algorithm I mentioned:
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon#Ray_casting_algorithm
- `function draw` is where all the action is, we collect all the matches from the svg path, then we build a polygon, then get the bounding box and loop over that to find what is inside and I'm drawing something if we are inside.

The only thing I left out is the correct regex pattern to find the matches:
`image.matchAll(/L(...),(...),/g)`
That works on my simplified example, you need to look for a proper one for your examples.

You might not need to do regex, it all depends on the structure in that  `countyGeoJson` you might be able to extract the polygon directly from that.

Comment: I am trying to understand this solution... Why are you drawing anything? And where are the `points` that OP is expecting as the output array?

Comment: @Luka `Why draw?` what better way to show that the point `[x, y]` is inside the polygon, collecting them in an array is hardly a challenge

Comment: Great answer, I will need time to digest it. First question: what is the regex doing exactly?

Comment: The `regex` is extracting all the coordinates from the SVG image, but look at the data on your might be able to do countyGeoJson you might be able to get it directly from that and skip the pathGenerator step

Comment: @InspectorDanno Now that I look at this with a fresh mind ... this is something a bit heavy to be doing at the browser ... Can you offload these calculations server side (could be done once and cached) then just pass the results to the browser?

Comment: That is a good idea, although I'm trying to go for a serverless implementation. What I can do is run the path generator function on the geoJson without drawing anything to the screen, regex the coordinates from those paths, and then run your algorithm. Cheers!

Comment: Still that is time/resources on the browser, it all depends on your application ... keep that in mind as you continue to add more features

Answer (score 1):

I think your algorithm is perfectly fine, you will hardly find more performant one in terms of big-O complexity.
Still, there are some improvements you can do in your code:

1) It is important to know how big is the canvas in comparison to all the features together. If the canvas is way bigger, then it might be beneficial to find bounding rectangle of all the features (one bounding rectangle for all of them together), and then do your search withing that rectangle, instead of the whole canvas. If the canvas is just a bit bigger, than probably this will not do any improvements.

2) You are doing some work (like calling `pathGenerator`) that is inside the innermost loop, although it doesn't depend on the variables of the outer loops. If this work is expensive, it is better to precalculate beforehand.

3) From your code, because of your `break;`, I can assume that if you find that the point belongs to one feature, then it doesn't belong to any other. If that is really true, then some ordering of the features might be beneficial if you are able to order them in smart way to break from the loop sooner. Without knowing any info about your features, I will make a simple assumption here: if a point belongs to some feature, then it is very likely that the neighbor point belongs to the same feature.

According to my points 2) and 3), this is the update to your code I am suggesting:

```js
// precalculate shapes outside the innermost loop (point 2. above)
// features with shapes (fws):
const fws = countyGeoJson.features.map(feature => {
  feature,
  shape: new Path2D(pathGenerator(feature))
});

const points = [];
const pointWidth = 2;

for (let x = 0; x < canvasWidth; x += pointWidth) {
  let lastIdx = 0;
  for (let y = 0; y < canvasHeight; y += pointWidth) {
    for (let i = 0; i < fws.length; i++) {
      // start with the last found feature (point 3. above):
      let j = (lastIdx + i) % fws.length;
      if (context.isPointInPath(fws[j].shape, x, y)) {
        points.push({ coords: [x, y], data: fws[j].feature.properties });
        lastIdx = j;  // remember this feature index for the next (x,y) point
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the pixels coordinate that the filling of your path would produce, **simply fill that path and get the pixels that have been painted.**

Since we don't want to have a too big canvas to search in, we can first extract the BBox of the <path> in the document, resize a canvas and inverse translate its coordinates from that BBox. We'll just have to re-add the translation when mapping the pixels back to coordinates:

```js
const path_elem = document.querySelector( 'path' );
const coords = getPathFillCoords( path_elem );

let str = '';
coords.forEach( ([ x, y ], i ) => {
  str += `<rect width="1" height="1" x="${x}" y="${y}" fill="${ Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'blue' : 'red' }"/>`;
} );
path_elem.insertAdjacentHTML( "beforebegin", str );

function getPathFillCoords( elem ) {

  const bbox = path_elem.getBBox();
  const def = path_elem.getAttribute( 'd' );
  const path = new Path2D( def );
  const canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
  const width = canvas.width = bbox.width;
  const height = canvas.height = bbox.height;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
  ctx.translate( -bbox.x, -bbox.y );
  ctx.fill( path );
  const img = ctx.getImageData( 0, 0, width, height );
  const pixels = new Uint32Array( img.data.buffer );
  const coords = pixels.reduce( (arr, px, ind) => {
    if( px !== 0xFF000000 ) { return arr; } // not fully opaque
    const ratio = ind / width;
    const y = Math.floor( ratio );
    const x = Math.round( (ratio - y) * width );
    const coords = [ x + bbox.x, y + bbox.y ];
    arr.push( coords );
    return arr;
  }, [] );
  return coords;

}
```

```css
body { background: white }
rect { opacity: 0.5 }
canvas { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<svg width="800" height="400">
  <path d="
      M588,173
      L588,176 L585,216 L585,216 L584,223 L580,274 L565,273 L565,273 L549,271
      L539,270 L535,269 L513,267 L503,266 L486,264 L477,262 L468,261 L464,260
      L455,259 L449,258 L451,249 L452,244 L453,233 L456,218 L456,215 L460,192
      L460,191 L462,180 L463,174 L463,171 L464,167 L464,161 L465,158 L470,159
      L471,159 L477,160 L477,160 L480,161 L482,161 L487,161 L499,163 L500,163
      L514,165 L534,168 L535,168  L544,169 L555,170 L557,170 L565,171 L581,173Z"
      fill="transparent" stroke-width="1" stroke="black">
</svg>
```